# When attempting to keep cursor centered, camera rotation is impaired

Tags: c++

I'm using C++/OpenGL to create a little FPS game, and I've run into an issue.

Here is the code for my camera rotation function:

```
OldMouseX = MouseX;
    OldMouseY = MouseY;

    GetCursorPos(&p);

    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);

    MouseX = p.x - CenterX;
    MouseY = p.y - CenterY;

    if ((MouseX - OldMouseX) > 0)  {           // mouse moved to the right
        heading -= 1.0f;
        yrot = heading;
    }
    else if ((MouseX - OldMouseX) < 0) {
        heading += 1.0f;
        yrot = heading;
    }

    if ((MouseY - OldMouseY) > 0)  {           // mouse moved up
        VertLook += 1.0f;
    }
    else if ((MouseY - OldMouseY) < 0) {
        VertLook -= 1.0f;
    }

    SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);
```

Now, what happens when I call

```
SetCursorPos(CenterX, CenterY);
```

it prevents my camera from rotating, simply jerking it slightly.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the camera for `MouseX - OldMouseX`/`MouseY - OldMouseY` (multiplied by a certain factor) and not constantly `1` each tick.